# Notepad++ text alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment, notepad++, preview

I am trying to create a simple document after recently starting to learn HTML and CSS. I am using Notepad++ with the plugin "Preview HTML".

The problem is the text in the preview window is centered by default(meaning i have to insert text-align to render any text left).

However, when I open my HTML file in a browser (without text-align), it displays text to the original left alignment.

Any idea how I can change the default text alignment in the "Preview HTML" window to left?

Below are screenshots depicting the problem

[Preview in "Preview HTML"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHSTq.png)

[Preview in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRFmd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried what you gave, and the reason is improper closing `<h2>` tag. You missed the forward-slash sign while closing. Causing the `<h2>` tag to never end and the below `<p></p>` tag was treated as enclosed inside this and thus style for parent tag i.e. `.heading` class got applied to the child tag of `<p>`

```
<h2 id="heading">Testing<h2>
```

should be

```
<h2 id="heading">Testing**</h2>**
```

for it to work.

screenshot of corrected html is below
[image]
screenshot showing what happened actually in DOM
[image]